# How to make Fiddler as a proxy simulator?

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I am writing an app that sends http requests to a remote server. My app must work if there is a proxy server. Therefore, I need set proxy settings of the http requests and do the tests.

My local PC doesn't have a proxy server. I downloaded the Fiddler Classic (Progress Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger). I knew the Fiddler works as a kind of proxy. But how can I  make the Fiddler as a proxy simulator, so I can get the simulator's proxy information and set it in my app, and test whether my app works if a proxy server exists? Thanks.

Comment: Fiddler does not "work as a kind of proxy" it is a HTTP proxy so you don't have anything you need to simulate. So you just have to configure the whole system or only the connections within your app to use fiddler as HTTP proxy. How to configure your app depends on the app OS, used programming language and used http client.

Comment: Hi Robert, How can I get the fiddler's URL, port number, and set username and password? I like to set these in my app and test if the settings are correct, let my request pass through the fiddler, otherwise I get an error, like 407 error.  Thanks.

Comment: Fiddler by default runs on port 8888 no authentication required. Open Fiddler Classic and enable in Options "Allow remote computers to connect". How to set-up that in your app depends on what "app" you are talking about (Android, iPhone, Windows, what programming language and what HTTP client is used?).

Comment: My app is a C# windows desktop. I should set proxy server url as 127.0.0.1:8888. But I cannot set authentication on Fiddler Classic, is that right? Thanks, Robert.